# Creating a program in R

Tags: r, dataframe, interface

Very simple question but i'm a beginner ans self taught so i can't ask my stupid questions to anyone. Is there an "easy way" in R to create a program that would show a window with text and you would have to input what you want and it would go look into a dataframe the answer to your question ? Not asking for you to do the work just if you could show me the way.
Thanks (Sorry for the english : not my mother tongue)

Comment: I think there are not stupid questions! You can use a Shiny Dashboard, but it's not very easy to start with R https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/

Comment: Maybe so, i meant an obvious one for someone who knows a bit about R. But wow that looks like exactly what i wanted i'll look into it asap. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: there probably isn't an "easy way" at least until you are a bit more experienced in R.

An easy way to do something *similar* is to read input from the console. This means you don't have a pretty window with text, but perhaps you don't need that.

```
pints_wanted <- readline("How many pints of milk do you want today? ")
```

If you definitely want windows, dialogs etc., then you could consider using the `tcltk` package, or the `rgtk2` package.

Comment: The goal was pretty much to have windows ann stuff even if it doesn't get too complicated, the issue being that I have to create an interface cause the people who are supposed to use the data don't do any kind of programming and are not familiar with R at all. I think the packages you quote might be what i want i'll take a look. Thank you